# android built-in camera folder

Tags: android, camera, directory, image

Phones come with different camera apps from the manufacturer, and they all store the pictures/videos in their respective camera folder in `"DCIM"`. (`Camera`, `camera`, `100ANDRO`, `100MEDIA`, etc etc). The thing I'm having problems with here, is to determine which exact folder name (case-sensitive) the built-in camera app uses for it's pictures and videos.

Please correct me if I'm wrong here, but some phones will have `"DCIM"`, others will have `"Dcim"` or `"dcim"`. Trying to match these names seems difficult, as matching is case-insensitive due to the File System format of the SD Card, and Android (Linux based) is of course case-sensitive, so any matching done will return true, but writing/read will fail, because the actual folder name is wrong.

Using `DIRECTORY_DCIM` from the public class `Environment`, will return the folder as "DCIM" in all cases (in my scenarios), regardless if the actual name of the folder is "DCIM", "Dcim" or "dcim".

Any suggestions are welcome. There has to be a 'right' way of doing this. Just matching with hardcoded strings is something I would like to avoid, but could be a last-hack option.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wrong. The name of the directory is as returned by `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DCIM)`

Comment: Then why would it return "DCIM" on several phones when the actual directory name is "dcim" (lower case) ?